# How to change dot method call to dictionary key access in Vim

Tags: vim

Say I have the following code

```py
config.file_path
```

and due to a refactor I need to rewrite as

```py
config["file_path"]
```

How would I write a reusable function to transform one to the other?

I'm not opposed to installing a package to help, but a pure Vim version would be super cool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to approach the problem this way: Find a useful generic transformation, then make it easily repeatable.

### Finding a useful transformation

If you're somewhere inside the word `file_path`, you can apply this transformation using: `F.s["<Esc>ea"]<Esc>`. (Note: you're meant to press the "Esc" key whenever I used `<Esc>`.)

Breaking this down:

- `F.`: Move backwards to the first `.` before the cursor.
- `s`: Substitute the current character, this will remove the `.` and enter insert mode.
- `["`: This is typed in insert mode, so inserted literally into the text.
- `<Esc>`: Leave insert mode, back to normal mode.
- `e`: Jump to the end of the current word, this will place the cursor on the `h` at the end of the word `file_path`.
- `a`: Append, this will enter insert mode right after the current character. Note this also works fine if `file_path` is the last word in the line.
- `"]`: Inserted literally, in insert mode.
- `<Esc>`: Leave insert mode, back to normal mode one last time.

This transformation does exactly what you want and it's fairly general to be applied in different cases.

Now let's see how to repeat it multiple times.

### Repeating a transformation.

You can record a sequence of commands into a **macro**. You do that by using the [`q`](https://vimhelp.org/repeat.txt.html#q) command, and specifying a register name (a lowercase letter), so you can later recall it.

Let's use the `k` register (`k` for "key", in your "key" transformation), so you start recording with `qk` and finish with a single `k`.

Place the cursor at an appropriate position (inside a `file_path` word you want to change) and type: `qkF.s["<Esc>ea"]<Esc>q`. (Note: you're again meant to press the "Esc" key whenever I used `<Esc>`.)

This will perform the transformation *and* record it on the `k` register.

After this is done, you can simply navigate to an instance of `file_path` you want to change and then use [`@k`](https://vimhelp.org/repeat.txt.html#%40) to replay it. Once you've used that once, you can use [`@@`](https://vimhelp.org/repeat.txt.html#%40%40) to replay the last used register.

If you're using a search, such as `/file_path` or perhaps `*` on top of a `file_path` word, then you can alternate `n` and `@@` to keep finding the next matches and applying the transformation.

### Using a mapping to make a more permanent keybinding

If you find this operation very useful and would like to make it more permanent, then consider making it into a mapping and adding it to your `.vimrc`.

Recording a macro to a register is fine, and in most cases it will be preserved in your `.viminfo` file (by default, it will be preserved), but you might end up overwriting it by accident with another `qk` command, or perhaps copying into that register with `"kyy`, those commands using `"` use the same registers. Furthermore, there are only 26 letters for registers, so eventually you'd run out of them if you kept using them for sequences you want to save long term.

You can use something like this in your `.vimrc` to create a more permanent mapping:

```
nnoremap <leader>k F.s["<Esc>ea"]<Esc>
```

Note: here you're supposed to type `<Esc>` literally, five keystrokes, `<`, `E`, `s`, `c` and `>`.

The [`:nnoremap`](https://vimhelp.org/map.txt.html#%3Annoremap) command will associate a keybinding to a sequence of keystrokes. In this case, it will associate `<leader>k` with the sequence of commands we've been using.

The [`<leader>`](https://vimhelp.org/map.txt.html#mapleader) prefix allows you to configure a custom prefix by setting the global `mapleader` variable. Assuming you haven't set it, it will default to `\` (backslash).

After adding that mapping and sourcing your `.vimrc` file, you can type `\k` to apply that same transformation.

You can then alternate `n` and `\k` to keep finding the next matches and applying the transformation.

### Search and Replace

You're still having to alternate search and replace. Why not do both in a single step?

You can add an `n` command to the end of your macro, so that once it's done with the transformation, it will jump to the next word.

If you still have your `@k` macro around, you can easily append to it by using the uppercase version of the register name.

For example, you can use this: `qKnq`. Breaking it down:

- `qK`: Start recording, now **append** to the end of register "k".
- `n`: Go to the next match of the previous search.
- `q`: Stop recording.

Now your `@k` will apply the transformation *and* skip to the next match.

You can cycle through using `@@` to apply the transformation and jump to the next match, then apply it again with another `@@`, or skip that particular instance of it using `n` instead.

In particular, if you want to replace *all* instances of that search term in your buffer, you can use `999@k`, which will replace up to 999 instances of them.

Be careful, though, if you're searching for `file_path` alone, that word will still be present after the transformation, so you might want to make sure you're only matching it following a `.`, with a search like the one below:

```
/\.\zsfile_path\>
```

Breaking it down:

- `/`: Start a search.
- `\.`: Match a literal dot.
- `\zs`: Make the match start at this point, so this is where the cursor will end up, and this is also the part that will be highlighted when `'hlsearch'` is set.
- `file_path`: The word to match.
- `\>`: Match a word boundary, to make sure you're matching a whole word only.

After such a search, using `999@k` with the macro recorded above, including the final `n`, will transform all instances in the buffer (assuming there are not more than 999 of them.)

### Alternative Approach: Make it Repeatable

One snag with our first approach is that we can't repeat it with `.`, since we enter insert mode at two different spots of the command and we use motions using the `F` command.

If we managed to perform the whole substitution using a single command, we would be able to repeat it using `.` (and also undo it using a single `u`!)

It turns out we can.

This would work: `ciw<BS>["<C-R>-"]<Esc>`. (Note: press the backspace key on `<BS>`, press Control+r on `<C-R>` and the Escape key on `<Esc>`.)

Breaking it down:

- `ciw`: Change inside word. If the cursor is anywhere inside `file_path`, this will substitute that whole word. Note the word itself will be deleted.
- `<BS>`: Use a backspace (in insert mode) to delete the `.` which precedes it.
- `["`: Insert these characters literally.
- [`<C-R>-`](https://vimhelp.org/insert.txt.html#i_CTRL-R): Insert the contents of the `-` register. The `-` register holds the last small (less than a line) delete. Since you just started a change operation with `ciw` and that will delete a word, that word is what will be in the `-` register, so you'll be adding it back in the middle of your replacement.
- `"]`: Entered literally.
- `<Esc>`: Leave insert mode, back to normal mode one last time.

This transformation can be repeated with `.`, so you can now alternate `n` and `.` to keep finding the next matches and applying the transformation.

### Search and Replace with Repeat

Repeat is nice, but you're still typing `n.n.n.` repeatedly, so let's get this one step further.

In order to do both search and replace repeatable, you can use the [`gn`](https://vimhelp.org/visual.txt.html#gn) command to select the next match (what would be found by `n`), but select it as a text object.

If you're using the search we previously used, you can then use `cgn` to substitute the *next* match for that term.

So you could search for: `/\.\zsfile_path\>`. Then substitute the next occurrence with `cgn<BS>["<C-R>-"]<Esc>`. Then repeat with `999.` to replace all occurrences.

Or, even more directly: `999cgn<BS>["<C-R>-"]<Esc>`.

### Why bother? What have we learned?

It's true that you can accomplish the same with a `:s` command, so why bother with macros, repeats, `gn`, etc.?

Well, for one, here we're using normal mode commands, which are regular editing commands we can use all the time. This has many advantages:

- We can use what we already know. (And the commands we learn here will be useful in other contexts.) To contrast, `:s` is much heavier in use of regexps, so now we need to master a second mini-language (Vim regexp flavor.)
- Immediate feedback. We can see things as they're getting transformed, while with `:s` you usually do the whole operation and hope you got it right, otherwise need to restart from scratch. With the normal mode commands you can also pause before a transformation, navigate to get more context about the current match, etc. You can also switch gears, change something else, then pick up where you left.
- This approach is more flexible. In fact, see how you have choices of macros, keybindings, repeats, etc. It's also much easier to compose normal mode commands, while `:s` gets a *lot* more complex if you want to have it do more.

While `:s` is a great tool to have in your belt, learning these techniques can be very useful to help you get things done in Vim.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that simple regexp substitution should be enough:

```
:%s/\<\(\h\w*\)\.\(\w\+\)\>/\1["\2"]/g
```

Here `\<` and `\>` denote the word borders; `\(` and `\)` are submatches. So anything of a form `word1.word2` will become `word1["word2"]`.

If you think that there could be some "false positives" (e.g. comments, literal strings, etc.), you can add `c` flag for manual confirmation.